# Create a new list from 2 lists after custom sort

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of ordereddict which i fetch from DB through a function and they look like below

**First list printed output:**

```
OrderedDict([('Items', '1'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 223.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '2'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 243.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '3'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 263.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '4'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 323.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '5'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 333.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '6'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 343.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '7'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 353.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '8'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 13.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '9'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 123.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '10'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 162.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('Items', '11'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 213.513353868968)])
```

**Second list printed output:**

```
OrderedDict([('planneditems', '1'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 23.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('planneditems', '4'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 113.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('planneditems', '5'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 133.513353868968)])
OrderedDict([('planneditems', '6'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 213.513353868968)])
```

I want to take every Flip value from second list and subtract that with all the Flip values of first list and insert the corresponding key value pair into first list where the difference between the values is lesser like below, this is to maintain the order of first list values(as they are already sorted)

**Steps:**

```
Take first flip value of second list : 23.513353868968
Subtract this with all the flip values of first list
23.513353868968 - 223.513353868968 = -200 (ignore the sign)
23.513353868968 - 243.513353868968 = 220
23.513353868968 - 263.513353868968 = 240 
23.513353868968 - 323.513353868968 = 300
23.513353868968 - 333.513353868968 = 313
23.513353868968 - 343.513353868968 = 320
23.513353868968 - 13.513353868968 = 10
23.513353868968 - 123.513353868968 = 100
23.513353868968 - 162.513353868968 = 139
23.513353868968 - 213.513353868968 = 190
```

In the above result, the difference is lesser for the flip value 13.513353868968 of first list , so i need to pick the  key value pair of the flip value 23.513353868968  from second list which is

```
OrderedDict([('planneditems', '1'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 23.513353868968)])
```

and place that between the first lesser difference and second lesser difference i.e it has to go next to items 8 line in the first list

Like this i want to fetch all the values from second list and repeat the same thing, at the end the second list  inserted according to the custom sort and they should also be sorted within themselves

**New List expected printed output:**

```
    OrderedDict([('Items', '1'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 223.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '2'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 243.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '3'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 263.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '4'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 323.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '5'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 333.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '6'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 343.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '7'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 353.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '8'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 13.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('planneditems', '1'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 23.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('planneditems', '4'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 113.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '9'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 123.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '10'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 162.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('Items', '11'), ('Itemspaid', 'Rutr'), ('First', 'Het'), ('Second', 'Fru'), ('Third', 'yurn'), ('Flip', 213.513353868968)])
    OrderedDict([('planneditems', '6'), ('plannedItemspaid', 'pRutr'), ('PlannedFirst', 'pHet'), ('PlannedSecond', 'pFru'), ('PlannedThird', 'pyurn'), ('Flip', 213.513353868968)])
```

i tried the below code , i am not able to make this work as expected, it prints out the last entry , any help would be appreciated.

```
for G in List2:
    diffs = []
    indexvalue=List2.index(G)
    for i in range(1, len(List1)):
        d1 = (G['Flip'] - List1[i - 1]['Flip'])
        d2 = (G['Flip'] - List1[i]['Flip'])
        t = (d1 + d2, i)
        diffs.append(t)
        j = min(diffs)[1]
new_xs=List1[0:j] + [List2[indexvalue]]+ List1[j:]
print(new_xs)
```

Comment: How is it printing multiple lists? You have one `print` statement outside the `for` loops. One issue with your code as written is that the insertion also only takes place outside the `for` loop, so only the last entry in `List2` makes it into `new_xs`. See https://www.ideone.com/IXJJfm for the output from your code.

Comment: Correct, it just prints out only the last entry.. how can i make it to give me the list with all the values sorted?.. Have edited the question..sorry

Comment: The algorithm for finding the insertion point is also unclear (and your code is inconsistent with what you've written). For example, you calculate `d1` and `d2` without taking the absolute value (`abs`), but your comment when you list the steps says, "ignore the sign." If two items from the second list are slated for insertion between the same two items in the first list, which goes first?

Comment: first list order has to be maintained as it is, If two items from the second list are slated for insertion between the same two items in the first list, items can be slated anywhere as long as they stay near the number where they have lesser difference

Comment: For one, `j = min(diffs)[1]` belongs outside the inner `for` loop. It won't make a difference answer-wise, but it's inefficient because only the last call (once `diffs` is fully populated) matters. Then, you have several options. One is to build a list of `(j, indexvalue)` tuples, sort it by `j`, and merge `List1` and the new list into `new_xs` (maintain an insertion-position offset that starts at `0` and gets incremented on each insertion).

Comment: can you please post the solution code if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
insertions = []
for G in List2:
    diffs = []
    indexvalue=List2.index(G)
    for i in range(1, len(List1)):
        d1 = abs(G['Flip'] - List1[i - 1]['Flip'])
        d2 = abs(G['Flip'] - List1[i]['Flip'])
        t = (d1 + d2, i)
        diffs.append(t)
    j = min(diffs)[1]
    insertions.append((j, indexvalue))
insertions.sort()
new_xs = []
last_j = 0
for j, indexvalue in insertions:
    new_xs += List1[last_j:j]
    new_xs.append(List2[indexvalue])
    last_j = j
new_xs += List1[last_j:]
print(new_xs)
```

[Output](https://www.ideone.com/GrdWmr) doesn't match your expected output, but I'm sure your expected outfit isn't correct, anyway (e.g. planned item 5 is missing).

Comment: :( in the output the planneditems 4 should be before items 9, but it is not.
regarding the expected output, i didnt include all of them

Comment: @Python_newbie Why should it be before Items 9? You say to "ignore the sign" and your code minimizes the sum of distances to adjacent elements in `List1`, so by this logic it belongs after Items 9.

Comment: Planned items 4 is 113, items 9 is 123, so Planned items is lesser and hence should come before items 9

Comment: can you please post the revised code for having the planneditems 4 before items 9

Comment: So are you inserting into a rotated, sorted list then in `Flip`-sorted order? Then why are you calculating distance? Find the pivot and do a binary search to insert each element from `List2` or something.

Comment: i did not have that idea, just wanted a simple one...that is why. Basically the order in list 1 is fixed and second list should fit into the order of first list as sorted

Comment: if the list 1 starts even from the number 300 it should stay the same, the list 2 values should be inserted into list 1 based on the order of list1, that is why i have chosen the closest distance

Comment: Calculating distance will not yield the correct solution based on my updated understanding of your problem. Find the insertion index using binary search, similar to [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/description/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172214/discussion-between-python-newbie-and-user1093967).